# What is the meaning of this sentence "And I'll never take it for granted" in this song?

Tags: expressions

I'm studying English and I came across this new expression. I researched, but in Portuguese it has several different meanings, some of them even contradictory. So I'd like to know from the American perspective, what the idea of that phrase is. Here is the lyrics of the song (joe Inoue - Closer):

*You know the closer you get to something*

*The tougher it is to see it*

**And i'll never take it for granted**

*Let's go!*

And the translations I've already found:

And I'll never get used to it.

And I'll never be satisfied.

And I'll never think this will ever be like this forever.

etc

Comment: Did you look up the phrase **take it for granted**?  What did you find?

Comment: Yes, i did. In portuguese we don't have a similar expression, but in most cases it's like "tomar por certo". But it really doesn't fit into the music (or at least i think so)

Answer (score 2):

In general, to **"not take things for granted"** just means to appreciate what you have. In this context, it seems that we are saying that we can't take advantage of things that were worked hard for in order to achieve, and we can't treat privileges like rights. I found a few verbs that seem to have the same meaning in Portuguese: presumir, asumir, and supor.

Answer (score 1):

@ElenderGóisGallas  Your translation is probably accurate.  Lyrics to songs don't always fit the context -- they often mean something special to the person who wrote them, which may not be obvious to everyone else.  Or, in this case, a Japanese songwriter using a common English phrase in a way that means something to his audience, but may not be a standard use of the phrase.

In general,  To "take something for granted" simply means not to properly *appreciate* it.

> I always **took my mother's cooking for granted**, until I moved out and had to cook for myself.

"I'll never take it for granted," means, "I'll always appreciate it."  I don't know what "it" is, but you may be able to figure that out from the rest of the lyrics -- at least, those that aren't in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest (of what you have found) is

> And I'll never get used to it

but in the sense of ceasing to appreciate the value of something. That is, in the beginning you have something that you appreciate or value but that over time you become used to it as "normal", the novelty/uniqueness or special feeling fades away and you no longer ascribe it the same value that you did in the beginning - you take it for granted.